# Как получить все значения из таблицы сгруппировано?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Всем привет. Есть вопрос к группировки значений из таблицы MySQL. Задача следующая, у меня имеется таблица примерно с такими данными:

| ID | Tbl2_ID | Tbl3_ID | Information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Information_1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Information_2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | Information_3 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | Information_4 |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | Information_5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Поля **"Tbl2_ID"** и **"Tbl3_ID"** связи с другими таблицами в БД. Записи добавляются в разнобой, и я хочу сгруппировать и отсортировать данные, вывести упорядоченно группами по двум полям (**Tbl2_ID** и **Tbl3_ID**).

Пробовал использовать `Select * From Table Group By(Tbl2_ID , Tbl3_ID )` но выводит первые 2 записи совпадения... Не могу понять, как получить упорядоченную коллекцию, которую в представлении Laravel я бы перебрал foreach и красиво оформил в объединенную таблицу...

Примерно так должен выглядеть результат исходя из выше представленной таблицы (чтобы было понятно, чего я хочу добиться):

| ID | Tbl2_ID | Tbl3_ID | Information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Information_1, Information_4 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Information_2, Information_5 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | Information_3 |

Comment: Не получается, так он просто все записи выведет, потому что ID уникальный для каждой записи

Comment: А если так `Select * From Table Group By(Tbl2_ID && Tbl3_ID)`?

Comment: Не выходит, выводит первое совпадение в Таблице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT row_number() over(order by Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID) id,
Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID,
group_concat(Information) Information
FROM Table
GROUP BY Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID
order by 1;
```

Comment: Спасииибо! Помог ответ! Только если не трудно, объясните зачем использовали "row_number() over(order by Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID)" и в конце "order by 1"? Я модифицировал запрос, добавил сепаратор, для более красивого вывода:  "SELECT id, Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID, group_concat(Information, SEPARATOR '\n') Information FROM Table GROUP BY Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID" и у меня всё получилось...

Comment: row_number() - для последовательной нумерации результатов.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, тут группировка не нужна вообще. Тут нужен просто порядок вывода. См. ниже.
GROUP BY группирует данные при выборке, имеющие одинаковые значения в некотором столбце, а что нам тут одинакового выводить? При аггрегированных функциях ещё он хорош.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
ORDER BY Tbl2_ID, Tbl3_ID
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ... Да я так пробовал, запрос отсортировал выборку, так я получу упорядоченный набор, но проблема, в таком случае, заключается в представлении, при выводе не знаю, как написать алгоритм, чтобы вывести в читабельный вид...